# Why is rihlata in 106:2 mansoob?

Tags: arabic

> eelafihim rihlata ash-shita'i was-sayf - 106:2
>
> (their accustomed security in the caravan of winter and summer)

106:2 has the word رِحۡلَةَ (rihlata - caravan/journey) with the مَنصُوبُ (mansoob - accusative) case.  But I don't understand why.  It's not the object of any verb.  It's not being used as an adverb of manner.  None of the sisters of إِنَّ (inna) are anywhere in sight.  So what is this particular use of the مَنصُوبُ (mansoob) case?

Comment: This is a question on Arabic language not Islam. And this certainly is an object related to the verb "فَلْيَعْبُدُوا" and it is stated to be the object of the source of إيلافهم. This whole surah is grammatically interesting because an Arabic sentence either starts with a noun or a verb and neither of that is the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mansoob because it is the object of the verb in إِيلَافِ. The word إِيلَافِ is itself a masdar, but it contains a verb inside it in meaning. Masdar, ism faa'il, and ism maf'ool can act like verbs in some senses due to there being a verb inside them in meaning.

It is possible you can think of the sentence as: لِأنْ آلَفَهم رِحْلَةَ الشِّتاءِ والصَّيْفِ.

For other examples of this, see: وَأَكْلِهِمْ أَمْوَالَ النَّاسِ بِالْبَاطِلِ v4:161 and وَقَتْلِهِمُ الْأَنْبِيَاءَ v4:155 and إِطْعَامٌ فِي يَوْمٍ ذِي مَسْغَبَةٍ يَتِيمًا ذَا مَقْرَبَةٍ v90:14-15

In v4:161, أَمْوَالَ is maf'ool bihi to the verb inside the masdar أَكْل. In v4:155, الْأَنْبِيَاءَ is maf'ool bihi to the verb inside the masdar قَتْل. In v90:14-15, يَتِيمًا is maf'ool bihi to the verb inside the masdar إِطْعَامٌ.